# Air conditioner function

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, simulation

I have a problem. I'm beginner at Javascipt and there is one problem that I can't solve. " An air conditioner has a built-in thermometer that measures the room temperature. When the user enters the desired temperature into the remote control, it starts working, but its fan speed depends on the difference between the actual temperature and the desired temperature. If the difference is bigger than 10 degrees, the fan’s speed is 3x, if it is bigger than 5 but less than or equal to 10, fan speed is 2x, and between 0 and 5 degrees, fan speed is 1x. Write a JavaScript function to simulate the air conditioner" This is the problem. And I wrote code below but it returns 1x for every number I tried. Can you help me please?

```js
function airConditioner(aT, dT) {
  var difference = function (aT , dT) { 
    return Math.abs(aT-dT); 
  }
  if (difference > 10) {
    return "3x";
  } 
  else if (difference < 10) {
    return "2x";
  } 
  else if (5 < difference || difference < 10) {
    return "2x";
  } 
  else { 0 < difference || difference < 5
    return "1x";
  }
}

airConditioner(19, 15);
```

Comment: Review the code you have posted. Also learn how to debug your code. Start [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/).

Answer (score 3):

You need the result after calling the difference function or just the result of the absolute delta.

BTW, you need no else parts, because if returned, the function has finished.

Then you need to check only greater values and return if fount. The following check assumes a smaller value, so no more check for the upper bound is necessary.

```js
function airConditioner(aT, dT) {
    var difference =  Math.abs(aT - dT);
  
    if (difference > 10) {
        return "3x";
    }
    if (difference > 5) {
        return "2x";
    }
    return "1x";
}

console.log(airConditioner(19, 15));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you are great :)